# Finding highest value in mixed list then returning name of item and item + VAT%

Tags: python

For my college work, I need to import a list from another python file and then get a value from it. The list goes like Name, Size, Price, VAT Rate. We are not allowed to change the list or import anything other than the python file (which contains loads of other values)

From this list, I need to find the highest value and also return the item name as well as print the value with the added VAT. I thought about finding the highest number value, finding out the percentage (not sure how yet) then going back 2 values to find the name but I'm not sure how to code that. I've looked around for a while and I'm not able to find any solutions. I'd appreciate any help if possible!

```
sweetshop_array = [ "Innocent Orange Juice Smooth", "1.35L", 3.2, 0,
"Tropicana Orange Juice Original", "0.95L", 2.48, 0,
"Growers Harvest Pure Apple Juice", "1L", 0.69, 0,
"Innocent Coconut Water", "1L", 3.69, 0,
"Sensations Thai Sweet Chilli Crisps", "150G", 1.0, 0.2,
"Popchips Original Popped Chips", "85G", 1.85, 0.2,
"Pringles Salt & Vinegar Crisps", "200G", 2.5, 0.2,
"Kettle Chips Lightly Salted Crisps", "150G", 1.99, 0.2 ]
```

Comment: Do you know the `max` function? Did you try to use it? Do you know that it has a `key` parameter?

Comment: I tried but I got an error, I think I might have done it wrong possibly? I did print (max(sweetshop_array)) to test if a max value would appear and I got an error (TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str') and we haven't learned key parameters, kinda got all this dumped on us with no lessons about it as our revision material given doesn't cover it

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is that the data structure you have shown is not suitable for this task. Instead of one flat list there should be a nested list like `sweetshop_array = [ ["Innocent Orange Juice Smooth", "1.35L", 3.2, 0],
["Tropicana Orange Juice Original", "0.95L", 2.48, 0], ...]`. You might need to create this first. Then you can use the `max` function on it. If you reorder the items in the sublists to that the prices come first, `max` will return the item with the highest price.

Comment: Yeah, most places I looked at had nested lists, but we're not allowed to touch the list at all. Is there any way to convert it within my python file without editing the original list? Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: You do not need to change the list. You can create another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i didn't get this wrong, should work:

```
sweetshop_array = [ "Innocent Orange Juice Smooth", "1.35L", 3.2, 0,
"Tropicana Orange Juice Original", "0.95L", 2.48, 0,
"Growers Harvest Pure Apple Juice", "1L", 0.69, 0,
"Innocent Coconut Water", "1L", 3.69, 0,
"Sensations Thai Sweet Chilli Crisps", "150G", 1.0, 0.2,
"Popchips Original Popped Chips", "85G", 1.85, 0.2,
"Pringles Salt & Vinegar Crisps", "200G", 2.5, 0.2,
"Kettle Chips Lightly Salted Crisps", "150G", 1.99, 0.2 ]

max_value = ['name','size',0,0]

for index in range(0,len(sweetshop_array),4):
    name = sweetshop_array[index]
    size = sweetshop_array[index+1]
    price = sweetshop_array[index+2]
    vat_rate = sweetshop_array[index+3]
    max_value = [name, size, price, vat_rate] if price > max_value[2] else max_value

max_value_name = max_value[0]
max_value_added = max_value[2] + (max_value[2] * max_value[3])

print(max_value_name, max_value_added)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, I will look more into indexes as I checked them out but didn't understand how to implement them, once again thanks for the help!

Comment: if this answer helped you, [you can accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lambda` method:

```
sweetshop_array = [ "Innocent Orange Juice Smooth", "1.35L", 3.2, 0,
                    "Tropicana Orange Juice Original", "0.95L", 2.48, 0,
                    "Growers Harvest Pure Apple Juice", "1L", 0.69, 0,
                    "Innocent Coconut Water", "1L", 3.69, 0,
                    "Sensations Thai Sweet Chilli Crisps", "150G", 1.0, 0.2,
                    "Popchips Original Popped Chips", "85G", 1.85, 0.2,
                    "Pringles Salt & Vinegar Crisps", "200G", 2.5, 0.2,
                    "Kettle Chips Lightly Salted Crisps", "150G", 1.99, 0.2]

sweetshop_array = [sweetshop_array[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(sweetshop_array), 4)]

print(max(sweetshop_array, key=lambda x:x[2]))
```

Output:

```
['Innocent Coconut Water', '1L', 3.69, 0]
```